# JDBC How to pass parameter in the query having LIKE Clause

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

**Problem : Passing parameters does not work with query having LIKE Clause**

I am trying to pass a parameter in the parametrized query.

Working Fine:

```
String Query = "Select * from ABC where name=?";
Connection con = sql.getSqlDOConnector().getConnection();
PreparedStatement selectStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
selectStmt.setString(1, "ABC");
ResultSet rs5 = selectStmt.executeQuery();
```

Having Issues:

```
 String Query = "Select * from ABC where (LOWER(NAME) LIKE \'% ? %\')";
   Connection con = sql.getSqlDOConnector().getConnection();
   PreparedStatement selectStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
   selectStmt.setString(1, "ABC");
   ResultSet rs5 = selectStmt.executeQuery();
```

I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5303) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5291) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:278)
```

Any idea on why I am getting this error while working with Parametrized queries having LIKE clause? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: `PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE notes like ?");`  `pstmt.setString(1, "%ABC%");`

Comment: This has been answered several times before -- please search before posting.

Comment: Hi Satya, So, if I am passing not hardcoded parameter ..something like below   String Name =  "Steve" and pstmt.setString(1,Name), then how would I add % in the setString? Thanks for ur help

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder for pointing out the answer. This has helped.